# NGRX call server just at the end

Tags: angular, redux, angular-promise, ngrx, ngrx-effects

In my Angular application I have an effect (handled when the application starts) that retrieve the available langs from the server. I'm going to save the **lang[]** inside an object (**GlobalData**) saved in the application Store.
In the login component I subscribe to the property **isFetchingLangs**, a boolean, that if it is true it will disable the login.
So the steps of the effects are the following:

1. Get the GlobalData from store
2. If there are langs set the **isFetchingLangs** to false and save the fact that the GlobalData is created; otherwise call the service;
3. Preparing the actions to dispatch: if the GlobalData is not present, I add the langs and add the action to save GlobalData.  set the **isFetchingLangs** to false

This is the code:

```
coreActions$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(CoreActions.GET_AVAILABLE_LANGS)
    .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromApp.getGlobalData))
        , take(1) 
        , map(([action, storeState]) => {
            if (storeState && storeState.langs && storeState.langs.length) {
                this.globaDataCreated = true;
                return this.store.dispatch(new CoreActions.GetAvailableLangsFinished());
            } else {
                return from(this.langsService.getAvailableLangs());
            }
        })
        , mergeMap((langs: Lang[]) => {
            let actions = [];
            if (!this.globaDataCreated) {
                this.applicationUrl = this.urlService.getApplicationUrl();
                let newGlobalData = new GlobalData(
                    false,
                    null
                );

                langs.forEach(lang => {
                    newGlobalData.langs.push(lang)
                });
                this.translate.use('en');
                this.moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");
                actions.push({
                    type: CoreActions.SET_CORE_APPLICATION_DATA, 
                    payload: newGlobalData
                })
            }

            actions.push({
                type: CoreActions.GET_AVAILABLE_LANGS_FINISHED
            })

            return actions;
        })
        , catchError((err, caught) => { ...... }
```

The service:

```
getAvailableLangs(): any {
    return this.http.get<CommonClasses.SenecaResponse<CommonClasses.Lang[]>>(this.applicationData.applicationContext + 'rest-api/langs');
}
```

**Issue:** it enters in the mergeMap((langs: Lang[]) => { ....} before to call the service this.langsService.getAvailableLangs()

**Target:** wait untile the getAvailableLangs() finished, and then set isFetchingLangs to false and do other operations

****** ***EDITED CODE AFTER @JANRECKER ANSWER*** *********

```
getAvaibleLang(storeState?: GlobalData) {
    if (storeState && storeState.langs && storeState.langs.length) {
        return this.store.dispatch(new CoreActions.GetAvailableLangsFinished());
    } else {
        return this.langsService.getAvailableLangs();
    }
}

@Effect()
coreActions$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(CoreActions.GET_AVAILABLE_LANGS)
    .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromApp.getGlobalData))
        , take(1) 
        , switchMap(([action, storeState]): Lang[] => this.getAvaibleLang(storeState))
        , mergeMap(
            (langs: Lang[]) => {
                if (langs) {
                    const applicationUrl = this.urlService.getApplicationUrl();
                    let newGlobalData = new GlobalData(
                        applicationUrl,
                        false,
                        null
                    );
                    langs.forEach(lang => {
                        newGlobalData.langs.push(lang)
                    });
                    this.translate.use('en');
                    return [{
                        type: CoreActions.SET_CORE_APPLICATION_DATA,
                        payload: newGlobalData
                    }, {
                        type: CoreActions.GET_AVAILABLE_LANGS_FINISHED
                    }];
                } else {
                    return [{
                        type: CoreActions.GET_AVAILABLE_LANGS_FINISHED
                    }];
                }
            }
        )
        , catchError((err, caught) => {....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware, that "map" changes the content of the stream.

```
of('helloWorld').pipe(
    map((data:string):number => data.length) // data.length = 10
).subscribe(
    (data:number) => console.log(data) )  // 10
)
```

You wrote something like (i use typings to make it a bit more obvious)

```
of('helloWorld').pipe(
    map((data:string):Observable<number> => from(data.length))
).subscribe(
    (data:Observable<number>) => ... )
)
```

So you created an observable in an observable stream. :-)

If you want to open a second stream, "mergeMap" would be the right choice.
If the first stream did all you want, and you want to work now on a different stream "switchMap" would be my choice.

Just to get a better feeling of the code, i would extract everything out of the stream into methods. Something like

```
coreActions$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(CoreActions.GET_AVAILABLE_LANGS)
    .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromApp.getGlobalData))
        , take(1)
        ,switchMap(([action,storeState]):Lang[] => this.getAvaibleLang(storeState) )
        ,tap(() => this.setApplicationUrl() )
        ,tap((langs:Lang[])=> this.setLanguages(langs) )
        ,tap(()=> this.pushLanguageAction() )
   )
```

With the intensive use of typeings, i think it gets more readable.

warm regards

Comment: First of all thank you! Then, "So you created an observable in an observable stream" --> for the from() method? P.S. I've edited my question, I added the new code related on you answer, and it seems works... could you check it?

Comment: P.S. I had to use mergeMap() at the end, even if in a case (the last case) I return just one action... in fact I wrapped it into array: return [{type: CoreActions.GET_AVAILABLE_LANGS_FINISHED }]... I don't know if it is a good practice.. but if I used a map() I couldn't return 2 actions (the first IF case)

Comment: Why not "map"?
... map((lang:Lang[]):Actions[] =>{... do magic and return any array of Actions }
Or do you would like to create one (or two) Action events in the stream? So not an Array of Actions but two singular Action events that got through the stream?
So that a subscriber would be called two (or one :-) ) times?
And yes, the "from(xy)" method is a creation Method of an Observable, so it created in your first version an Observable in your Observable stream.